# Neo4j Python 4.4 API using timeout

Tags: python, api, neo4j, timeout

I'd like to break my Neo4j query after 1 second by starting but it doesn't work.

I use this Python code:

```py
query = "text of neo4j query, doesn't matter"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri="doesn't matter")
session = driver.session()
result = session.run(Query(query, timeout=1.0), name='query')
d = result.data()
```

My long queries are hanging indefinitely and I don't how to break them.

In the API documentation 4.4 Neo4j Python library is a lot of ways to do it, but none of them work (may be it's my mistake but I don't understand why).

Answer (score 0):

I found this documentation that explains the setting to put a timeout in the configuration file.

> https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/understanding-transaction-and-lock-timeouts/

At the bottom of that documentation, I tried using this APOC function apoc.cypher.runTimeboxed and it works well.  The last parameter is 1 ms so it is not returning the data when using 1ms and returns a data when I put 100ms.

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

query = """
    CALL apoc.cypher.runTimeboxed("MATCH (n:Person{name:'Keanu Reeves'})-[*]-(other)
    RETURN count(*) as allPathsCount",
    {}, 1)"""
    
uri="bolt://localhost:7687"
user="neo4j"
password="password"

driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=(user, password))

session = driver.session()

result = session.run(query)
d = result.data()

print(d)


Using 1ms:  []
Using 100ms:  [{'value': {'allPathsCount': 12}}]
```

Comment: Good work! @Thesaurus.  Please accept/upvote my answer too. There is a check and arrow up buttons across my answer. Thanks.